# Possible error in evaluating kernel gradient in scikit-learn's GPR

Tags: python, scikit-learn, gaussian-process, rbf-kernel

Perhaps I am missing something very obvious, but in the [standard kernels](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/gaussian_process/kernels.py) associated with scikit-learn's Gaussian process regression framework, the radial basis function (RBF),

$$f = e^{-x^2/2l^2},$$

has its gradient evaluated with respect to its hyperparameter, $l$. This should be equal to:

$$\frac{df}{dl} = \frac{x^2}{l^3} f,$$

yet in the code, the output appears to be (c.f. [line 1233](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/19c8af6d6a9528162fd41d8a3363b807e337d63d/sklearn/gaussian_process/kernels.py#L1233) and neighbouring code):

$$\frac{df}{dl} = \frac{x^2}{l^2} f$$
I am wondering if I am perhaps missing something in the applied definitions and/or steps involved, or if this is actually an error in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because scikit-learn by default automatically optimises the hyperparameters of the Gaussian process regression kernels by maximising the log-marginal-likelihood, which requires the calculation of the derivative of the kernel with respect to the *logorithm* of the hyperparmeter, $l$, rather than just the hyperparameter itself.

We can see from the chain rule that the derivative of the kernel, $f$, with respect to the logrithm of $l$ is given by:

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial \mathrm{log}\ l} \frac{\partial \mathrm{log}\ l}{\partial l} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial l}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial \mathrm{log}\ l} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial l} \big/ \left(\frac{\partial \mathrm{log}\ l}{\partial l}\right)
\end{equation}

Since the derivative of the natural logrithm of $x$ is equal to $1/x$, we get:

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial \mathrm{log}\ l} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial l} \big/ \left(\frac{1}{l}\right) = l \frac{\partial f}{\partial l}
\end{equation}

Therefore, substituting in the derivative for $\partial f/\partial l$ you found earlier:

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial \mathrm{log}\ l} = l \frac{x^2}{l^3}f = \frac{x^2}{l^2}f
\end{equation}

Which is exactly the expression you found in the code!